# Show only number pad for pin input

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number" Height="50" />
```

[image: This shows way more than just the number pad.]

How to change this so it shows 0-9, ., and the buttons on the far right>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try `TelephoneNumber` or other options you see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue.aspx.

If these don't work - you'd need to craft your own UI.